# ASP.NET MVC with React - how to use them in a combination

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web

I have a newbie question. If we use React (or any other similar framework) in ASP.NET MVC we end up with very simple (single?) cshtml file which delegates UI rendering to React. So in that case, why bother with MVC? Shouldn't be a better idea to create WebAPI REST service, and a frontend client application in pure JavaScript/React as two completely separated applications?

I just don't get the idea of using ASP.NET MVC in combination with different frontend frameworks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you're correct in that you would not use a typical MVC setup when using something like React or Angular. That said with the newer versions of ASP.NET there is no difference between an API controller and an MVC controller. You'd write your API endpoints in this new unified controller and use it like a standard RESTful API for your React application to hit. You can keep both in the same solution and serve up the index.html to start your web application.

In my experience it is better to just separate the two entirely and built a .Net back end in one VS solution and then use something like WebStorm to write your web application in another.

Answer (score 2):

Compared to pmanderson54's answer, he is right about separating .NET back end and React Front end apps.

**Just don't forget to configure enabling Cross-origin Requests in Web Api**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api